# Keep alive webRTC audio stream on Android

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, webrtc, html5-audio

I have built a webRTC application that streams audio.

The application works as intended on all devices and the client is able to hear the audio stream. At a very high level, the RTC stream is simply attached to an audio element which works great.

The problem: I am trying to utilize the Android Chrome background audio feature. At the moment the stream keeps playing in the background (even when chrome is minimized) however about 5 seconds after screen timeout/lock, the peer connection is closed. This is not a memory issue (I have several test devices including a Galaxy S7).

In contrast if I simply point to url of an mp3 file, the audio context will keep playing indefinitely. Is there a way to achieve this indefinite background with a webRTC stream?

Cheers in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verified resolved in issue 513633 with no background logic required: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=513633

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this old bug made its way back into Chromium :
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=951418